# Localization files in app bundle

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have localization with 3 languages.  Everything was working; then I wanted to change something in localization files.

My changes didn't have any effect, and I can't figure out the reason.
The big idea that it worked and still is finding old resources.

This is working for me when I want to print the bundle of localization file:

```
PATH/MyFirsy.app/en-LT.lproj> (not yet loaded)
```

My steps:

- Getting your resource files ready for localization
- Collecting all the texts used in the application in resource files
- Translating the resource files
- Integrating the resource files back in the application

Maybe someone who had this problem could help me.

Comment: Are you talking about NIB files?

Comment: @Streetboy your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for localization to be in affect, you also need to change your simulator's/device's language. you can check the same in your case.